Polyfills Not Loading on Android for Angular 17 App, Causing Null Error
So, I have an angular project. The web works perfectly fine on a computer, but not on my phone.
I have an androin 13 phone.
I tried multiple browsers.
When I tried debbuging it, I got this error after the page loaded:
 null
at H.formatMsg (<anonymous>:40:32704)
at new H (<anonymous>:40:29734)
at M.insertSync (<anonymous>:20:30333)
at <anonymous>:20:31787
at u.<computed> (http://url:4200/polyfills-V5EMCUNT.js:4:1079984)
at n.invokeTask (http://url:4200/polyfills-V5EMCUNT.js:4:1065473)
at T.runTask (http://url:4200/polyfills-V5EMCUNT.js:4:1060746)
at invokeTask (http://url:4200/polyfills-V5EMCUNT.js:4:1066546)
at A.useG.invoke (http://url:4200/polyfills-V5EMCUNT.js:4:1066446)
at m.args.<computed> (http://url:4200/polyfills-V5EMCUNT.js:4:1079614)

I am using angular 17
I tried to import different things into polyfills.ts as I found that could be a problem, but that didn't help. I then tried to put console.log('Polyfills started loading...') to see if the polyfills even load, but the log never happened on my phone.
I don't know what to do anymore, so any help will be appreciated.
Please note that I'm quite new to angular.
